# how send code confirmation in amazon-cognito-identity-js and nest.js

Tags: typescript, amazon-cognito, nestjs

i have this example of nest.js + aws cognito login https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/token-validation-with-aws-cognito-and-nestjs-6f9e4088393c
i wanna send code that comes by mail for confirm my user and I do not know if I must modify it the Registeruser Service or Create Other Method in the service and controller.

```
import { AuthConfig } from './auth.config';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
  CognitoUserPool,
  CognitoUserAttribute,
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private userPool: CognitoUserPool;
  private sessionUserAttributes: {};
  constructor(
    @Inject('AuthConfig')
    private readonly authConfig: AuthConfig,
  ) {
    this.userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
      UserPoolId: this.authConfig.userPoolId,
      ClientId: this.authConfig.clientId,
    });
  }

  registerUser(registerRequest: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
  }) {
    const { name, email, password } = registerRequest;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return this.userPool.signUp(
        name,
        password,
        [new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'email', Value: email })],
        null,
        (err, result) => {
          if (!result) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(result.user);
          }
        },
      );
    });
  }

  authenticateUser(user: { name: string; password: string }) {
    const { name, password } = user;

    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: name,
      Password: password,
    });
    const userData = {
      Username: name,
      Pool: this.userPool,
    };

    const newUser = new CognitoUser(userData);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return newUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: result => {
          resolve(result);
        },
        onFailure: err => {
          reject(err);
        },
      });
    });
  }
}

import { BadRequestException, Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('register')
  async register(
    @Body() registerRequest: { name: string; password: string; email: string },
  ) {
    return await this.authService.registerUser(registerRequest);
  }

  @Post('login')
  async login(@Body() authenticateRequest: { name: string; password: string }) {
    try {
      return await this.authService.authenticateUser(authenticateRequest);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new BadRequestException(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i can resolved, i add a new method in service and call in the controller.

```
 confirmUser(user: { username: string; confirmationCode: string }) {
        const { username, confirmationCode } = user;
    
        const userData = {
          Username: username,
          Pool: this.userPool,
        };
        const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(confirmationCode, true, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           reject(err);
          } else {
           resolve(result);
          }
         });
        });
       }
```

---------------------------controller--------------

```
@Post('confirm')
  async confirm(@Body()  confirmUser: { username: string; confirmationCode: string }) {
    try {
      return await this.authService.confirmUser(confirmUser);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new BadRequestException(e.message);
    }
  }
```